# How to start an activity in Asynck task?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am getting error for executing intent in Asynctask. please show how to..

```
public class Livechat extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_livechat);

    MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
    myTask.execute();

}

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatWindowActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ChatWindowActivity.KEY_GROUP_ID, "3");
        intent.putExtra(ChatWindowActivity.KEY_LICENCE_NUMBER, "7584151");
        startActivity(intent);

        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `Livechat.this` instead of `this` as first parameter to Intent constructor.like         `Intent intent = new Intent(Livechat.this, ChatWindowActivity.class);`

Comment: @Mohammed KEY_GROUP_ID Integer or String ???...... Pass Integer Not String if Integer.... if Both Integer than Send as Integer....

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTask is actually another class within activity class, so use Activity class context to switch to another activity, as 'this' refer to 'class MyTask' context.
Use 'Livechat.this' instead of 'this'.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Livechat.this, ChatWindowActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ChatWindowActivity.KEY_GROUP_ID, "3");
        intent.putExtra(ChatWindowActivity.KEY_LICENCE_NUMBER, "7584151");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may face problem of starting intent in doInBackground, start Intent in **onPostExecute**

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Livechat.this, ChatWindowActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ChatWindowActivity.KEY_GROUP_ID, "3");
    intent.putExtra(ChatWindowActivity.KEY_LICENCE_NUMBER, "7584151");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is in this line

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatWindowActivity.class);
```

"this" will not work here as you are in AyncTask and this will be instance of AsyncTask only. You should use Livechat.this here and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Activity launching and other UI updating tasks should be performed in on `UiThread` not as a background task so you should always perform these tasks in `onPostExecute'

Somthing like this example:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { 

    // Perfrom other actions that you want to get done before launching other activity.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Livechat.this, ChatWindowActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(ChatWindowActivity.KEY_GROUP_ID, "3");
        intent.putExtra(ChatWindowActivity.KEY_LICENCE_NUMBER, "7584151");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

but in your case if you just want to launch the activity then there is no use of `AsyncTask` but if you want to perform some action before activity launch then you can do it in `doInBackground'

Hope it helps

Comment: Replace `this` with `Livechat.this`.